# convert gender from character to numeric value in R

Tags: r

I want to convert the character variable of gender into numeric. The structure of gender variable in character is like this:

```
$ Gender               : chr  "Woman" "Man" "Non-binary"
```

I have used this method to convert it to numeric:

```
ms$Gender[ms$Gender=='Woman']<- 1
ms$Gender[ms$Gender=="Man"]<-2
ms$Gender[ms$Gender=="Non-binary"]<-3

ms$Gender <- as.numeric(ms$Gender)
```

Is there any more efficient ways than this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use:

```
ms$Gender <- match(ms$Gender, c("Woman", "Man", "Non-binary"))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```r
ms$Gender <- case_when(
    ms$Gender == "Woman" ~ 1,
    ms$Gender == "Man" ~ 2,
    ms$Gender == "Non-binary" ~ 3
)
```